# Php script stop right after creating subdomain

Tags: php, shell, scripting, subdomain, plesk

All finally works, but my connection to the server is reset when I confirm the registering process, so... the subdomain is create but the script stop right after that, do anyone know why and can help me with this?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can't catch question, what do you mean under "new user register", there a lot of types user's in plesk. What is relationship between "subdomain" and "database"?

Comment: I mean that the user register through the website, so a website user registering. And, in the database I have the information that gave me the user, so I want to take these informations from database to my script to create the subdomain with the correct url and correct information about the user.

Comment: How you call shell command? What is the PHP error message you get at calling command in "system"?

Comment: I use the subdomain creation command of Plesk, by using system(/opt/psa/....) with all parameters, I don't get a PHP error, it only get me a MySQL error that it cannot access the database, and that is because the subdomain failed to be create, and when I do it manually from a terminal, all works properly. /:

Comment: Finally my script is fully functionnal, except that the user who execute it from my server is "www-data", and using command to add subdomain need root privilege... how can I do to make this command to be used by root, without making www-data root which is a really bad idea if I understood well on internet?

Comment: All finally works, but my connection to the server is reset when I confirm the registering process, so... the subdomain is create but the script stop right after that, do anyone know why? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Plesk Event Handlers is useful in case you need to add hook on some action on plesk, like domain creation.

In your case you may use API or CLI for creating necessary entities in Plesk from your PHP code.

For CLI you may have permission issues because all CLI calls should be performed as root, or called via sudo.

I suggest you to make all interaction with plesk CLI asynchronously - there a various approaches to make it in PHP, you should google how to do it.

Comment: I tried from Plesk CLI interface, but it's pretty struggling with passing argument, i'll google it but, i'm not sure it can handle the script and all the arguments it needs. Thanks.